# Hp procurve 2510 ssh problem

Tags: hp-procurve, ssh, authentication

My app connects to switches via ssh to gather info from them. I can connect  to any model except this one. I get the authentication error from the switch yet i can connect via putty with the same credentials. Do you have any suggestions for the solution?

Comment: Can I ask what ssh library your app is using?  You may find that it has different ciphers and key exchange algorithms to your putty client.  I'd also suggest checking that the error is actually authentication as opposed to something like no matching cipher.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Check whether there's a host key on the 2510:

```
show crypto host-public-key
```

If not, generate one:

```
crypto key generate ssh
```

You might also want to check for firmware updates - host keys are auto generated except for ancient firmware versions. The current version for 2510G is Y.11.52.

Also, you might want to look into SNMP as a possibly better interface with the switch.